# Why does the resultant force from static fluid is always perpendicular to the gate?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Why does  resultant force of fluid acting on a curved gate is always perpendicular to the gate at point where the resultant force at on the gate
Mathematical proofs appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried an attempt/ research (where have you looked?)  yourself, and a drawing  of the problem might help . Best of luck with it though.

Answer (score 1):

AS far as i can understand the question, consider the following proof.Suppose at any point of the fluid layer in contact with the gate, The reaction is $\vec R$. Consider the direction normal to the gate surface to be given by $\hat n$ and the direction tangential to it to be given by $\hat t$.Notice, if the fluid is to be static(by assumption), $\vec R$ . $\hat t$ (dot product) must be zero, because otherwise a shear stress will develop, causing fluid flow. Clearly then , $\vec R$.$\hat n$ = |$R$|. Hence, it is always perpendicular to the surface in contact, if the fluid is at rest.

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced that your proposition is generally true. Do you have any reference for it?

Here is a counter-proof :

If the proposition is true for a curved surface, it must also be true for a surface made up of flat sections, because a curved surface can be approximated by many flat surfaces.

Consider an L-shaped gate, in any orientation in the fluid. Let the normals to each face be $\hat x$ and $\hat y$. The force of the fluid on the gate at each point is perpendicular to the gate at that point. So on the $\hat x$ section the resultant force must be in the $\hat x$ direction and on the $\hat y$ section the resultant force is in the $\hat y$ direction. The overall force on the gate is the vector sum of these 2 forces, which clearly is in neither the $\hat x$ nor the $\hat y$ direction.

However, there is no point on the gate which is neither in the $\hat x$ or $\hat y$ direction. Therefore if the centre of pressure lies somewhere on the gate the resultant force cannot be in the direction of the perpendicular at this point.

Answer (score 0):

According to Pascal's Law, the pressure in a fluid acts equally in all directions.  Another way of saying this is that pressure can be considered an isotropic stress.   A key feature of an isotropic stress is that it always acts perpendicular to a surface at each location along the surface (i.e., in the direction of a unit normal to the surface).

Since you are asking for a mathematical formulation, here it is:  The stress tensor for fluid in static equilibrium is given (in dyadic tensor notation) by $$\vec{\sigma}=P(\vec{i}_x\vec{i}_x+\vec{i}_y\vec{i}_y+\vec{i}_z\vec{i}_z)$$where the i's are unit vectors in the coordinate directions.  Let $\vec{n}$ represent a unit vector normal to a solid surface, such that $$\vec{n}=n_x\vec{i}_x+n_z\vec{i}_y+n_z\vec{i}_z$$If we apply Cauchy's stress relationship to determine the force per unit area acting on the surface, we obtain:$$\vec{\sigma} \cdot \vec{n}=P(n_x\vec{i}_x+n_z\vec{i}_y+n_z\vec{i}_z)=P\vec{n}$$This is a vector with magnitude P in the direction of the unit normal.

Comment: And will the sum of all of these forces be normal to the surface?

Comment: If the surface is curved, the direction of the normal changes along the surface.  To get the resultant force on the surface, the pressure forces have to added (integrated) vectorially.